# Rmagick / ImageMagick unfuzz

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, crop, rmagick

How do I unfuzz?

```
image = Magick::Image::read(<file_path>).first
image.fuzz = "15%"
image.trim!
```

If I try to do a crop (or crop based operations like resize_to_fit or resize_to_fill) on the image after the trim, the crop is bad because (in my theory) the fuzz is still on.

So currently I'm "resetting" the image by saving it and reading it again:

```
image.write <file_path>
image = Magick::Image::read(<file_path>).first
```

But I'm sure there is a better way to reset/unfuzz but I couldn't find anything on that on the web.

Comment: `image.fuzz="0"` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mark Setchell is correct as far as resetting the value of fuzz. However, because fuzz is using when comparing pixel colors, I very much doubt that fuzz is making your cropping "bad". Maybe if you describe the problem in more detail you can get a better answer.